# Comment comprendre « les droits d'accès sont sécurisés » ?

Tags: sens, informatique

Dans un appel d'offres, la phrase

> Les droits d'accès sont sécurisés.

veut-elle dire:

- *The functioning of the access permissions is guaranteed/ensured* ?
- *The access permissions are "safe from unauthorized access"* ?
- ou *The access permissions are backed-up* ?

Il n'y a pas de contexte, c'est seulement

> **Généralités techniques:**
>   1.1 ...
>   1.2 ...
>   1.3 ...
>   1.4 ...
>   1.5 ...
>   1.6 ...
>   1.7 Les droits d'accès sont sécurisés.

Comment: The second one is correct.

Comment: Tu cherches à traduire l’appel d’offre pour d’autres (et dans ce cas, il faut probablement conserver l’ambiguïté) ou à y répondre (et, dans ce cas, ne peux-tu pas demander des éclaircissements ?) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La phrase est ambiguë en français.

Le mot *sécuriser* signifie « rendre sûr » ou « rendre plus sûr ». Dans un contexte technique de la sécurité des flux d'information, *sécurisé* signifie que l'on garantit une propriété de sécurité, en général l'une des [trois principales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA_triad#Key_concepts) : confidentialité, intégrité ou disponibilité.

Comme la disponibilité est le parent pauvre, on la mentionnerait explicitement. Il est donc possible, mais improbable, que la phrase signifie que les droits d'accès sont sauvegardés pour éviter leur effacement.

Les droits d'accès n'ont en général pas besoin d'être confidentiels. Il est donc possible, mais improbable, que la phrase signifie que les droits d'accès sont maintenus confidentiels.

L'interprétation la plus évidente de *sécurisé* ici est que l'intégrité des droits d'accès est garantie, c'est-à-dire les droits d'accès sont protégés contre toute modification par une personne non autorisée.

Une autre interprétation est possible : que ce ne sont pas les droits d'accès eux-même qui sont sécurisés, mais que ceux-ci sécurisent le système. Cela signifierait que les droits d'accès assurent (ou contribuent à assurer) la sécurité du système. La phrase signifierait donc que les droits d'accès doivent être déterminés de manière à n'autoriser à chaque personne ou entité que l'accès aux biens auxquelles elle doit avoir accès. La voix passive se justifie parce que c'est le concepteur du système qui règle les droits d'accès pour sécuriser le système — il sécurise donc les droits d'accès.

Au final je pense que la phrase veut probablement dire que les droits d'accès doivent être configurés correctement, et que c'est le rôle d'une des parties concernées d'effectuer cette configuration. Il est toutefois possible que la phrase signifie que les droits d'accès doivent être protégés contre toute modification non autorisée — le contexte devrait alors inclure d'autres propriétés du même type. Quoi qu'il en soit, la phrase demande à être clarifiée.

En anglais, on peut rendre l'ambiguïté en traduisant par *secured*. Le mot en anglais a toutefois encore plus de sens (en particulier, il peut vouloir dire que leur présence est garantie, mais cela n'aurait pas vraiment de sens vu le contexte).

Answer (score 3):

Je penche pour une mauvaise maîtrise du jargon de la part de l'auteur (ou de ma part, dans ce cas, ma réponse est à jeter).  J'aurais compris *les accès sont sécurisés* comme indiquant que seules les personnes autorisées peuvent avoir accès à certaines informations ou fonctionnalités et il me semble probable en l'absence d'un contexte faisant penser autre chose que ce soit le sens désiré.

Il me semble improbable que l'utilisation de *les droits d'accès* soit adéquate. Il y a bien l'éventualité ou des droits sont l'objet de la sécurisation, et non le moyen de leur mise en oeuvre. Par exemple, s'il s'agit d'un système de badges d'ouverture de portes et qu'il faut limiter les possibilités pour quelqu'un de non autorisé de savoir et modifier qui peut passer ou. On se retrouverait alors avec un double système de droits et celui qui écrit un appel d'offre pour un tel document aurait du établir une nomenclature claire pour éviter les ambiguïtés.

Answer (score 1):

"**Sécuriser**" is a relatively new word in French, meaning either :

- to give security to somebody ;
- to give a feeling of security to somebody ;
- to reassure somebody ;
- to secure, to increase the security of something (information, site, network, payment, transfer of funds, etc.).

You may say :

"sécuriser l'accès à quelque chose" = to make access to something more secure

" l'armée a sécurisé la zone" = the army improved security in the area

**In your example, it doesn't mean at all that the access is guaranteed (*the whole system could often break down*), nor that there is a back-up (*a fall-back could be catastrophic*); but only that a fraudster, or a spy, could not get access into the system in any circumstances.**

Comment: *Sécuriser* est ici dans un contexte technique et peut avoir une interprétation un peu plus élaborée que dans l'usage courant — voir ma réponse (je suis professionnel du domaine). Le sens « access is guaranteed » est possible, mais improbable.

Comment: @Gilles Votre réponse est parfaitement pertinente, mais peut-être trop technique pour le client ; bien que professionnel de l'audit informatique, je crois qu'il faut se mettre à la place de l'utilisateur, tel qu'il comprend l'expression : "personne qui ne connaît mon mot de passe / questions dont les réponses ne peuvent être connues que de moi / tout autre système biométrique (suivant le principe : ce que l'on est seul à savoir / à être)", donc personne ne pourra avoir accès à mes informations que moi, même en dérivant la ligne de communication.

Comment: Il s'agit d'un appel d'offres, qui en théorie est censé être validé par une personne technique (pas forcément un professionnel de l'audit, ce que je ne suis d'ailleurs pas, mais au moins quelqu'un de compétent s'agissant de l'objet ou système qui est vendu, lequel inclut un aspect lié à la sécurité).

Comment: Pas en droit français ; je suis aussi expert-judiciaire en informatique, et le fournisseur a une obligation de conseil et de mise en garde envers l'utilisateur supposé incompétent dans des techniques complexes : la Loi et la Jurisprudence sont formelles.

Answer (score 0):

Peut être plus simple : **Access rights are secured**

Comment: Ça a certes le mérite de conserver l'ambiguïté.